# Does CreateTextFile create a race condition over OpenTextFile?

Tags: file-io, vbscript, text-files, filesystemobject

My script iterates over a large amount of data in a .xlsx file and, depending on whether or not the file exists yet, creates/opens a file with respect to the data set it's currently working on.

The code that handled determining whether the `FileSystemObject` should create/open the text file ended up causing a portion of the data to be repeated in the beginning of the *text* file.  Once changed to working with a single file there were no repeats meaning the logic which handled extraction of data is fine.

```vb
Set excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set excelWorkbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\data.xlsx")
Set excelSheet =  excelWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

id = ""
sum = 0
row = 2

Do While row < 40500
    'identifier located in column c
    id = excelSheet.Range("C" & row).value

    'followed by numbers in column h
    'column h is empty on the row of an id
    Do While Len(excelSheet.Range("H" & row+1).value) > 0 
        sum = excelSheet.Range("H" & row+1).value + sum
        row = row + 1
    Loop

    WriteToText id,row,sum
    sum = 0
    row = row + 1
Loop

Sub WriteToText(x, y, z)
    fileName = "C:\file" & x & ".txt"
    If fso.FileExists(fileName) Then
        Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(fileName, 8)
        file.WriteLine x & " " & y " " & z
        file.Close
    Else  
        Set file = fso.CreateTextFile(fileName)
        file.WriteLine x & " " & y " " & z
        file.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

Is this a result of not freeing the memory space once the text file is created, processed, and closed?

```
Set file = Nothing
```

...causing a buffer created with `CreateTextFile` to persist through memory once `OpenTextFile` is called?

Comment: What does `!eof` refer to? Is it even valid syntax?

Comment: It's pseudo code.  Didn't occur to me that it wasn't valid syntax in vbscript since I mostly work in C/C++.  You can assume that I have the correct condition that detects when it ahs reached the end of the data.

Comment: If you are going to provide pseudo code please state it in the question, ideally to help you work out the problem we need a [mcve], emphasis on the "complete". Like @ansgar-wiechers [mentions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41663176/692942) - *"Without seeing where your data comes from and how you pull it there's no telling where duplicate data might come from"*. We can't do that with incomplete examples.

Comment: I've added the condition that !eof represented.  Since it is such a simple script, I didn't realize the data processing would've been relevant & considered "complete" since it was confirmed to have nothing to do with the creation of duplicate data.

Comment: In this instance you do need `Set file = Nothing`, but only because you don't define `Dim file` inside the scope of the `WriteToText()` procedure. As it stands it will be assumed to be in the Global scope holding the `TextStream` object in memory for longer than necessary.

Comment: As @ansgar-wiechers points out the variable is removed from memory the minute it goes out of scope, at the moment `file` has the default scope of `Global` which means it won't go out of scope until it is either overwritten *(not sure how the memory is managed, during an overwrite versus release and then recreate and any implications that might have in terms of memory consumption)* or the script ends. If the `file` object is defined inside the scope of `WriteToText()` it will release the minute the procedure ends then be recreated when the procedure is called again.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the help- so the main problem lies with the way the global object is overridden with `OpenTextFile` & `CreateTextFile`

Comment: Possibly, it's just guess work really. I'm just trying to help you understand that scope is important. Declaring variables *(using `Option Explicit` is key)* helps with these types of problems.

Comment: @MattGalaxy Does the current sample code really still expose the behavior you described? Even if the `file` object is retained after the previous procedure call it's replaced before writing data to it, so that still doesn't explain why you're getting duplicate entries. Can you provide sample data that would allow us to reproduce it?

Comment: Precisely why I'm so confused Ansgar- I'd provide sample data if I could, but I may experiment with a smaller data set later. Best thing I can suggest is to just place random tidbits of data within the appropriate columns? The important aspect here is the creation of a file and then the appending of one.

Comment: @MattGalaxy you're really not getting it, we are here trying to help you but you insist on making us do the work for you. For us to provide our own sample data we have to check through the code and see what columns have to be provided, the code references `C` and `H`... We shouldn't be expected to do this, you should provide everything we need to reproduce the issue instead of assuming we will fill in the blanks. That is not what we are here to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing where your data comes from and how you pull it there's no telling where duplicate data might come from. I don't see an inherent race condition in your code, since VBScript isn't multi-threaded in the first place. However, you can avoid any issues pertaining to the distinction whether or not the file already exists by simply using the [`OpenTextFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s.aspx) method with the third parameter set to `True`. That will automatically create a missing file and otherwise append to it.

```
Sub WriteToText(x, y, z)
    fileName = "C:\file" & x & ".txt"
    fso.OpenTextFile(fileName, 8, True).WriteLine x & " " & y " " & z
End Sub
```

Setting objects to `Nothing` inside functions is [almost never required](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing/), because VBScript usually handles that automatically by itself.

Comment: I disagree. I've seen multiple times, especially with complex scripts, making sure you correctly release memory is beneficial. A key example being database connections if declared globally holding them for the life of the script is not advised. But a lot of that comes down to the structure of your code, the scopes being used etc.

Comment: @Lankymart [Related](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing/).

Comment: I'm aware of that article and absolutely agree with what Eric is saying but it is still dependent on the scope and not all code is correctly scoped. For example, an ASP page with a DB connection...I've seen it time and again where the connection is opened at the beginning and held open until the end when this is not necessary, even creating extra connections to handle other tasks during the page execution when in reality only one connection is needed and only while retrieving data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer- I've already ruled out the data processing part.  The sub is exactly where the duplicate data came from, because once it was replaced with a more succinct method (just writing to one file as opposed to multiple ones)- the data came out fine.  It's good to know that `OpenTextFile` supports a creation mode though...

Comment: Would also like to add that in the version of the script that worked- the file was open throughout and closed at the end.  As opposed to being closed each and every time the `WriteToText` sub was called.

Comment: Appreciate [the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41663176/2). +1

Comment: @Lankymart I don't think I said it's never required (at least I didn't mean to say or even imply that). I am quite positive, though, that it's not required in the context of this question, at least as far as `TextStream` objects are concerned.

Comment: @MattGalaxy Like I already said in my answer: without seeing your data processing (and preferable some sample input to reproduce the behavior) we won't be able to pinpoint where duplicates are coming from. In the code you posted I don't see anything that would retain data from previous calls.

Comment: Attempted to add clarification to the data processing (it's very simplistic), let me know what else I can do to provide assistance to answering my question.  I appreciate the help..